# Getting Android Studio Gradle Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After running **Android Studio** I got this error in the picture , Does anyone know how to fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android Studio 1.3 : (Method 1)

Step 1 : Open gradle.properties file in your Android Studio project.

Step 2 : Add this line at the end of the file

org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
Above methods seems to work but if in case it won't then do this (Method 2)

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (File > Close Project).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings.

Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Step 4 : Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 1024 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m.

Step 5 : Close or Restart Android Studio.

Comment: # Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. 
# sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

Comment: that's what i found inside gradel.properties file i deleted some of it to be able to add comment